# How do I put the user registration form on my front page?

Tags: 7, panels, users

I'm using Panels and have a panel page for my front page.  I found a discussion for Drupal 6 but the code doesn't work for Drupal 7:
http://drupal.org/node/257721

I would like to show the user registration form on the front page to make it extremely easy for new users to sign up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add a "New custom content" to a panel pane and add the following code to the body (you need to have PHP format selected):

```
<?php

if(user_is_anonymous()) {  
  $form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
  print drupal_render($form);
}

?>
```

It works :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try [Form Block](https://drupal.org/project/formblock) module which will convert user registration form into block.