# “Create new account” Block in drupal

Tags: 7, blocks, users

I am working on a Drupal project where I require a "Create new account" form on a content page. Can anybody help me out with this? Is there any module or any alternative to get "Create new account" as a block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this module http://drupal.org/project/formblock

Download and install the module. Navigate to admin/structure/block You can see Registration form as a block and choose the region to appear.

[image]

[User Registration to appear in a block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57758/user-registration-to-appear-in-a-block) taken from this source.

Answer (score 3):

You can can [create](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/easy-way-to-create-blocks-programmatically) block programmatically. And create your own callback function where you can call [drupal_get_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) and render `user_register_form`.

For example your callback function will look like this:
Basic example

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function yourmodule_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['my_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('My Custom Block'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}
function hook_block_view($delta = '') {
    switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_block':
          $block['subject'] = t('Register form');
          $block['content'] = yourmodule_block_register_callback();
     }
}


function yourmodule_block_register_callback() {
   $reg_form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
   $output = drupal_render($reg_form);
   return $output;
}
```

If you are not familiar with the creation of custom modules - [read this.](http://drupal.org/node/361112)

Comment: Is it not possible through modules or something which is not so programmatic.

Comment: it's not as difficult as it seems

Answer (score 2):

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/21553/23871

Create a new block, copy/paste this code in the body:

```
<?php

if(user_is_anonymous()) {  
  $form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
  print drupal_render($form);
}

?>
```

Make sure the block is set to **PHP filter**